# How and when are .metadata and .plugins folders created in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I want to know how and when are the .metadata and .plugins folders created in eclipse.

More specifically when and how does .plugins folder gets created in our workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.metadata/.plugins` will be created when any of the installed plugins asks for the plugin's 'state location' using the `InternalPlatform.getStateLocation` API.

This usually happens as soon as the workspace is created because plugins such as `org.eclipse.core.resources` and `org.eclipse.core.runtime` want to store information in the state location immediately.

Comment: thanks greg. But when and how is .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench created. bcz in my issue  when i close my rcp app it returns an error. By deff I found out tat this folder is not created and when I cpy this folder from my othr wrkspc it closes fine.  So, I want to know how tis folder "org.eclipse.e4.workbench" is created.

Comment: It is very difficult to say for a specific plugin, you would have to search through all the plugin's source code. I would think `org.eclipse.e4.workbench` probably creates the directory when it wants to save the `workbench.xmi` file.